# How to properly CORS fetch from the Wikipedia API?

Tags: cors, wikipedia-api

Chrome is allowing this CORS fetch, but FireFox is blocking it.

```js
fetch(
  "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=San_Francisco&prop=images&imlimit=20&origin=*&format=json&formatversion=2",
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "someone"
    }
  }
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

Firefox (61.0.1 Mac) console error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked:
The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=San_Francisco&prop=images&imlimit=20&origin=*&format=json&formatversion=2.
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

A similar fetch to the GitHub API works on Firefox.

```js
fetch(
  "https://api.github.com",
  {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "User-Agent": "someone"
    }
  }
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```

Comment: Both requests trigger Firefox to make a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before trying the GET request from your code. The reason the Wikipedia API request fails is that the preflight fails — because for that OPTIONS request, the Wikipedia API endpoint sends a response that doesn’t include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. The request to the GitHub API endpoint succeeds because for the OPTIONS request to that, the GitHub API endpoints sends a response that includes both the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header and an Access-Control-Allow-Headers response whose value contains User-Agent.

Comment: Because both requests add a User-Agent request header, they should (per CORS-protocol requirements) trigger a CORS preflight OPTIONS requests in all browsers. And the request to the Wikipedia API endpoint should (per CORS-protocol requirements) fail in all browsers (as it rightly does in Firefox) — because the preflight will always fail. The cause of what you’re seeing seems to be that Chrome for some reason isn’t actually sending a preflight OPTIONS request for either the Wikipedia API case or the GitHub API case. That seems like a bug in Chrome, since the violates CORS-protocol requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As originally described [here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/the-wikipedia-api-does-not-support-cors-requests/16595), since wikimedia website checks the origin using the query parameter `origin` and does **not** support [cors-preflight-request](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-preflight-request), you have to make sure a `GET` method is sent.

Removing the following in your example ensures a `GET` request is sent:

```
headers: {
  "User-Agent": "someone"
}
```

Here the updated example:

```js
fetch(
  "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=San_Francisco&prop=images&imlimit=20&origin=*&format=json&formatversion=2",
  {
    method: "GET"
  }
)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    console.log(json);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error.message);
  });
```